# How to stop tomcat and start apache2?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have this server, that i have not installed personally. There are Apache2 and Tomcat6 running together. I want to stop Tomcat6 and use Apache2 but when i do

```
 sudo service tomcat6 stop
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

if i type 'localhost' in my browser i get a '503 service unavailable' error. So how i can get Apache2 'take control'? I mean i want the default site of Apache2 to be displayed on 'localhost' instead of tomcat'one.

(If i type locahost with Tomcat running i get an "it works" welcome page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache2 will have control when Tomcat is stopped and you start Apache. With Tomcat running on same port, you are unable to start Apache. Solution to 503 error is in Apache logs.

Comment: True. In my case, they were running together for apache2 was told to run on port 8000. Stopping Tomcat and putting apache2 on 8080 was enough. I lost contacts with phpmyadmin though. It was reachable with myip/phpmyadmin and now gives page not found...